# python - the label is not in the [index]

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I was using for loop to create a function that by looking at the direction value in each row, to return a direction based on conditions.
I have split the whole dataset into two.
I am using:

```
def dir_func(df):
for i in df.index:
    if df.loc[i,'dir_1'] == ['E' or 'NE' or 'SE']:
        df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'E'
    elif df.loc[i,'dir_1'] == ['W' or 'NW' or 'SW']:
        df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'W'
    else:
        if df.loc[i,'dir_2'] == ['E' or 'NE' or 'SE']:
            df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'E' 
        elif df.loc[i,'dir_2'] == ['W' or 'NW' or 'SW']:
            df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'W'
        else:
            if (pd.Series(df.loc[i,'loc_01']).str.contains(
                ("\sEB\s" or "\sEast\s" or "\sEastbound" or "\sE\s"),case=False) \
            | pd.Series(speed_overspeed.loc[i,'loc_02']).str.contains(
                ("\sEB\s" or "\sEast\s" or "\sEastbound" or "\sE\s"),case=False)).bool()==True:
                df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'E' 
            elif (pd.Series(df.loc[i,'loc_01']).str.contains(
                ("\sWB\s" or "\sWest\s" or "\sWestbound" or "\sW\s"),case=False) \
            | pd.Series(speed_overspeed.loc[i,'loc_02']).str.contains(
                ("\sWB\s" or "\sWest\s" or "\sWestbound" or "\sW\s"),case=False)).bool()==True:
                df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'W' 
            else:
                df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'NA'
```

to iterate.

This function works well for my first splitted dataset, but when I tried to apply it to the second dataset it returns:

> KeyError: 'the label [891] is not in the [index]'

However, when I looked at the #891 value, it actually returns a row with values.

I wonder if anyone could help me with that problem, and I will be really appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: please see how to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Need some more information here. Like @VivekKalyanarangan suggested, a [mcve] would be a great start. As of right now, there is no way to tell what is going on since we do not have any functional or dysfunctional code.

Comment: When you say "when I looked at the #891 value," how are you accessing this value?

Comment: Hi @HenryWoody, I used df.loc[891]to access the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should understand (in python 3.x) that the results of

```
df.loc[i,'dir_1'] == ('E' or 'NE' or 'SE')
```

is always going to be `False` unless df.loc[i,'dir_1'] **is actually equal to** 'E'

So the `if` statements should be changed to something like

```
 if df.loc[i,'dir_1'] in ['E', 'NE', 'SE']:
```

Similarly, you can use `in` in the last comparison statement.

The final function would then be:

```
def dir_func(df):
for i in df.index:
    if df.loc[i,'dir_1'] in ['E', 'NE', 'SE']:
        df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'E'
    elif df.loc[i,'dir_1'] in ['W', 'NW', 'SW']:
        df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'W'
    else:
        if df.loc[i,'dir_2'] in ['E', 'NE', 'SE']:
            df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'E' 
        elif df.loc[i,'dir_2'] in ['W', 'NW', 'SW']:
            df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'W'
        else:
            if (df.loc[i,'loc_01'].lower() in ("\seb\s", "\seast\s", "\seastbound", "\se\s")) or (speed_overspeed.loc[i,'loc_02'] in ("\seb\s", "\seast\s", "\seastbound", "\se\s")):
                df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'E' 
            elif (df.loc[i,'loc_01'].lower() in ("\swb\s", "\swest\s", "\swestbound", "\sw\s")) or (speed_overspeed.loc[i,'loc_02'] in ("\swb\s", "\swest\s", "\swestbound", "\sw\s")):
                df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'W' 
            else:
                df.loc[i,'dir_fin'] = 'NA'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I did changed that part and forgot to update the question:) Also, the label issue still happens... If you could help me with that I'd be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you share some sample data, it might be easier for me to figure out how to help. If you like my answer, please up vote it. I am waiting for the sample data.

Comment: I have upvoted it, but maybe because my level is low, it did not show up. d = pd.DataFrame{'dir_1': [S, E], 'col2': [N, NaN], 'loc_01': ['I-80 EB','CR78'],'loc_02'=['I-80', 'I-80 WB']}). Please let me know if there's any additional info you need, thanks

Comment: Thanks. You do not have 'dir_2'  and 'dir_fin' in the columns. Also, for the function to work properly, you need those two columns and the speed_overspeed dataframe. Moreover, when defining the dictionary that you are supplying to the dataframe d, you need to be  consistent. You cannot have `'loc_02'=['I-80', 'I-80 WB']`. You should have `'loc_02':['I-80', 'I-80 WB']`

Comment: Hi @Nde Samuel Mbah, I changed based on your function and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the help. I have upvoted your answer again. Really appreciated!!!!!

Comment: I am happy I was able to help.